# initializing memory in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have this piece of code:

```
type mem_type is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector (15 downto 0); 
signal Mem : mem_type:= (X"269F",X"351A",X"7752",X"9152",
                         X"CCD1",X"7A8B", "A429",X"5758",
                         X"A325",X"BC3D",X"725D",X"B459",
                         X"7264",X"E241",X"74FC",X"19BC");
```

I am getting the following error at the line where I am initializing Mem:

> No array or record type can be found that has elements of types matching the aggregate.

Comment: Look for typos in the aggregate...

Comment: It makes a great example of why you should use consistent structured formatting for VHDL code. Line up the elements in the aggregate and your typographical errors stands out. Also I use an editor that uses color to distinguish between bit string literals and string literals, it stands out like a sore thumb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your initialisation values doesn't have an `X` before it to specify a hex value. Your code is then trying to put a string into a 16-bit `std_logic_vector`, which is of course an error.